# what does .val() returns if it fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a value using Jquery's `.val()` function -

```
$("myDob").val(birthDate);
```

Now I want to implement a logic like this -

```
if (insertion of value is successful) 
{
   Do something
}

Otherwise
{
   Do something else
}
```

How do I implement this? I basically want to handle a scenario where the insertion of value fails.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the insert thing here. Where are you trying to insert the 'birthDate'? The statement $("myDob").val(birthDate); creates confusion here. Please clarify you requirements.

Comment: .val will just return object reference back while setting value. You need to again call .val to get value and know about insertion success or not

Comment: I dont understand why this has been downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var birthDate = '01/01/1990';
$("myDob").val(birthDate);

// Now check val of myDob equal birthDate
if ($("myDob").val() == birthDate) {
   // do something
} else  {
   // do something else
}
```

Hope can help you! :3

Comment: Beware some values might not be returned (serialized) exactly like you did set it, even though it did work (e.g `$('input[type=color]').val('#FF00FF').val()` => `'#ff00ff'` lowercase).

Answer (score 3):

`.val()` is a setter if called with an argument. And it returns the element itself on which you have called the method. Case when it fails to insert is when the element itself does not exist.

So you can check if it exists or not by checking the `.length` property of the what `.val()` returns.

```js
var x = $("myDob").val("somevalue");

if (x.length) {
  console.log("1 Updated successfully");
} else {
  console.log("1 Updation Failed");
}


var x = $("#goodInput").val("somevalue");

if (x.length) {
  console.log("2 Updated successfully");
} else {
  console.log("2 Updation Failed");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="goodInput">
```

Comment: I don't think you got the question correctly nor the 3 upvoters (or maybe I missed it), but from my understanding OP wants to know if the value has been set, and your code don't check for it: e.g if instead of `$("myDob")`  you used `$(document)`, your script would wrongly report a success

Answer (score 0):

You can do same thing with different approach. Why not if we check `birthdate` variable is not `null` or `undefined`. If variable has an value then `val()` function definitely work.

```
if (birthDate != undefined || birthDate != null) {
    $(".YourClass").val(birthDate);
}
```

By above approach script will add value to selected element after checking the variable.